# Make Scrollbar track transparent

Tags: css, scroll

There are few questions here that ask the same but their solutions don't work for me.

This is a picture from one of those questions and what I want to achieve. I have a list and when there are more items, scrollbar shows up.

I also set the overflow-y to be overlay since I don't want the scrollbar to add to the width of the list. How can I make the track transparent so the items underneath can be seen?

[Track overlapping content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIJNS.png)

[Updated]: 
Fiddle to show how it looks now, the picture is what I want to get.

```
p {
overflow-y: overlay;
width: 101%; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yk1cverh/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following in your css code:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.7em;
  background: white;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #c0392b;
  height:30px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece
{
   display:none;
}
```

In this part:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.7em;
  background: white;
}
```

You can change the  `background: white;` to any color you want. You probably need to make it similar to your body's background color or set it to transparent.

Here is a JS Fiddle that demonstrates it.

https://jsfiddle.net/qzsbf0tm/687/

Comment: I copied the fiddle and added the part I want to achieve. Look at the word test in red color, it still is underneath the scrollbar. It's ok to be when the thumb of the scrollbar moves over but the track should not hide it. https://jsfiddle.net/yk1cverh/2/

Comment: That is because you did
p {
    overflow-y: overlay;
    width: 101%;
}

do 

p {
    overflow-y: overlay;
    width: 100%;
}

It will no longer go on top  https://jsfiddle.net/yk1cverh/3/

Comment: But I want that effect with the width: 101%, I want the scrollbar to overlap the content without moving the word test into next line.

Comment: @SaraKat The code you provided doesn't achieve the result mentioned in the question.